# Fast "In nature" or Fast "by nature"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Let us say I am trying to come up with a sentence that talks about properties of a computer algorithm and I wish to say that the algorithm is inherently fast. which is the right way to say it?

```
The algorithm is fast in nature
```

or

```
The algorithm is fast by nature
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Nature** *noun*
>   1 [mass noun] The phenomena of the physical world collectively, including plants, animals, the landscape, and other features and products of the earth, as opposed to humans or human creations
>   2.1 The innate or essential qualities or character of a person or animal:  *I’m not violent by nature*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nature)

You ask, *which is the right way to say it?*

It's the second, using *by* nature (using definition 2.1 above). It means that the algorithm is fast *because of* its nature. As algorithms are not living things, they don't really have a *nature*. You can rephrase to say "it is *intrinsically* fast".

Your first sentence uses the word *nature* to mean the natural environment (definition 1 above). The sentence means that the algorithm is fast when used in nature (e.g. forests). It may be slow in other locations (e.g. cities), but this part isn't specified.

Comment: I saw a wild algorithm in nature once. Those things can run!